# Atom editor - TODO highlight for JS?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

In Atom editor, `TODO`s are automatically highlighted with `atom/language-todo` package, and I can change the style using user stylesheet. That much I know.

So I'm developing a webpage right now, and have to simultaneously work with HTML, CSS, and JS. However it seems that `TODO`s are only highlighted for HTML and CSS files, not JS files. This is strange because in the settings for `atom/language-todo`, the scope for all triggers are `.html.php.text` - HTML is included; CSS and JS are not. So reasonably thinking, either both CSS and JS should have highlight enabled, or both should have it disabled.

What is causing this strange behavior? Is there anything I can do to enable highlighting for JS?

P.S. Currently `mrodalgaard/atom-todo-show` is my alternate solution. It's quite good but I would still like to have my highlights.

Comment: Maybe something to do with this issue: https://github.com/atom/language-todo/issues/82

Comment: Thanks. Do you recommend disabling tree-sitter to fix JS highlighting as `macdonaldtomw` suggested in the comments? I tested and it works but I'm just wondering what functionalities I'm potentially losing by disabling it. Also I think I would accept this if you put it down as an answer. Or alternatively I can keep the question open for later viewers.

Comment: Github tree-sitter is Atom's new (from last year) code parser that should improve syntax highlighting speed and reliability. It is safe to disable it as long as you do not have problems with the old regular-expression based system. IMHO, you should try, and come back to the tree-sitter if your editing experience is degraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is probably related to this open issue on the `atom/language-todo` repository: https://github.com/atom/language-todo/issues/82.

As someone suggests in the issue conversation, the todo highlighting can be restored by disabling Atom tree-sitter in the settings:core page.

For more information on how the tree-sitter improves code parsing, see the [release article on the Github blog](https://github.blog/2018-10-31-atoms-new-parsing-system/)